# MySQL FULLTEXT search yields 0 for a one-letter difference

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a table, let's call it `A`, with a FULLTEXT index on its `name` field.
This table, containing around 1200 rows, contains a single row whose `name` field has a value of "TELEVISORI"

This query:

```
SELECT A.name, MATCH(name) AGAINST ('Televisori') AS `match`
FROM A
```

Results in (not the exact value, but I remember it being around 8):

```
+------------+-----------+
| name       | match     |
+------------+-----------+
| TELEVISORI | 8.3947893 |
+------------+-----------+
```

Whereas this one:

```
SELECT A.name, MATCH(name) AGAINST ('Televisore') AS `match`
FROM A
```

yields no results.

Things I've checked:

- The word is not a stop word
- Its length is over 4 characters (rather, 3 since I'm using InnoDB?)
- The word appears in less than 50% of records - It's the *only* one in hundreds.
- I tried changing the casing of the words in every possible combination just to be completely sure, but that shouldn't be it since I'm using a case insensitive collation. Also, it matches without  a problem when I use "Televisori"

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: So you want to look for `Televisore` and get results that contain `Televisori`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Is fulltext search the right tool for that or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: That's not what FULLTEXT searches are supposed to do but you can give query expansion modifier a try: `MATCH(name) AGAINST ('Televisore' WITH QUERY EXPANSION)`

Comment: That does seem to give far more results. I know it's a generic question about a really big field, but if I wanted to do things the "proper" way, how would I go about ti instead? Maybe coupling fulltext search with something like Soundex or Levenshtein?

Comment: Using soundex would work here but without benefiting from fulltext searches and their features. If you chose fulltext only to satisfy this requirement you can drop it easily. To have Levenshtein distance, you have to implement it for MySQL or use a language to build your query and send it to MySQL.

Comment: Yeah, for this one use Soundex seems to do wonders. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You appear to be looking for synonym lists or stemming.  I don't think either are supported by the built-in full text capabilities in MySQL.